# How can I locate the cell and do math by the data resulted from other cell in Excel-VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create excel Macro for my company. It looks like simple but I keep failing to get the result. I'm not a good VBA user so it would be big help for me if I got your assist.

The first sample template got "Dollor" amount and "No" fed from other source.

Now, my issue is on second template which needs to locate the cell at "Result" Column, using the row number from Cell " No " and paste "Dollor" amount ( Paste $100 at F5 on the sample sheet ).

```
Sub Test()
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F& B2.Value&").Select    
    ActiveSheet.Paste    
End Sub
```

[image: Sample Excel Sheet]

Comment: Please include the code you tried in your post, along with a description of the problem you're having when you run it.

Comment: What if there is already a number there, do we add, subtract, replace?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply on this. If there is a number there, then just replace it. Short test coding was                                                                                  
 Sub Test()
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F& B2.Value&").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the range reference you show use

```
Range("F" & Range("B2").Value)
```

And you can say

```
Range("F" & Range("B2").Value) =  Range("A2")
```

You should also include the full sheet reference to avoid implicitly working with the Activesheet.

An example, if sheet 1 could be:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("F" & .Range("B2").Value) = .Range("A2")
End With
```